# Biblatex no .bib inserted and no .bbl file created - using TeXnicCenter

Tags: biblatex, miktex, texniccenter

I tried to use `biblatex` for the first time, instead of BibTeX, which was fine, however LaTeX is obviously unable to insert the `.bib` file because the warning messages stay the same if I intentionally do not try to insert a `.bib`-file. Although I have been trying for several days, I could not find a solution to the problem.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Bibliographie.bib} 
@ARTICLE{Sample1998,
  author = {Sample, Susan G},
  title = {Military Buildups, War, and Realpolitik A Multivariate Model},
  journal = {Journal of Conflict Resolution},
  year = {1998},
  volume = {42},
  pages = {156--175},
  publisher = {Sage Publications}
}
\end{filecontents} 
\addbibresource{Bibliographie.bib} 
%\bibliography{Bibliographie} % Did not help either
%\bibliography{C:/Users/<Musterpfad>/Bibliographie} % Did not help either

\begin{document}
Test \cite{Sample1998}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this "Test [**Sample1998**] "
 I got no error but several warning messages:

```
BibTeX> WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file 2.5, expected version 2.3 % as well as
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Sample1998' on page 1 undefined on input line 23.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 25.   
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                Test
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Re-running LaTeX, even several times, did not change anything. 
Moreover the `.bbl` file is empty.

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 32bit version (early on I have used the 64bit - there was no difference) and TeXnicCenter 2.02, 32bit. In the latter one I have changed the `"path to the BibTeX executable"` from `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\bibtex.exe"` to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\biber.exe"`  I have the feeling that I should change something within the TeXnicCenter settings, therefore I attached my output profile.[image: texniccenter output profile]

Comment: `Warning: Found biblatex control file 2.5, expected version 2.3` states the problem. The version of `biblatex` and Biber do not match. Try deleting the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl` etc. pp.); if that does not help, [update your MiKTeX distribution](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/updating.html).

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. Deleting the temporary files, installing the newest biber version or updating MikTex did not help either. I reinstalled Texniccenter and miktex several times, always using the newest version of the programms.        However unsuccessful. What "Command line arguments to pass to BibTeX" have you?

Comment: Mhh, I don't use TeXnicCenter. The problem should not be related to TeXnicCenter; did you actually update MiKTeX or did you only re-install it? Try the following: Using the command line's `cd` command, navigate into the folder the `.tex` file is contained in; let's assume the `.tex` file is called `test.tex`, while the `.bib` file is called `test.bib`; invoke `pdflatex test`, then `biber test` and then `pdflatex test`.

Comment: Both: Reinstalling and updating it. Now I updated everything and the message "Warning: Found biblatex control file 2.5, expected version 2.3" disappeared (I checked it in the .log file, too). However the other four warning massages reported above remained. I am sorry, but I do not understand your suggestion, what is the "command line's cd command"?. I am compiling my .tex document several times like I did it as I was using bibtex but nothing changes.

Comment: When I said "command line's `cd` command" I intended to say: Open a command line (on Windows that is [`cmd.exe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMD.EXE)) and use `cd` to navigate to the proper folder. The idea was: Try compiling the document *not with TeXnicCenter*, but *manually*. So we can pinpoint whether this is actually a TeXnicCenter problem.

Comment: I have tried to compile the document with TexWorks and TexStudio as well. None of it worked. The errors were quite similar. All other Latex features - using Texniccenter - are working fine, except Miktex is still unable to include the .bib file.

Comment: Have you tried compiling manually though? What happens if you type `biber -v` into the command line prompt? You say "The errors were quite similar", was there any difference? Can you check if the `.bib` file does actually exist?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the exact same problem using Texmaker. After re-installing the current MikTex version, I figured that the Biber package was still not updated. Manually downloading the current Biber version (http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/) and replacing the old Biber.exe in the according MikTex file structure solved all problems for me.

Comment: got the same problem, your solution fixed this, thanx a lot for time saving.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using TeXnicCenter with biber an I use the following (a little bit different) configuration:

[image]

See the arguments to the LaTeX compiler (`%pm`). My call to biber instead of bibtex is the same.

If that does not help, your computer has a problem with your installation. Please delete your old installation (TeXnicCenter and MiKTeX), then **reboot** your computer.  Download the current MiKTeX, install it (I prefer the complete version), then download the current TeXnicCenter and install it. Now create a new profile for biber and it should compile (I have `-synctex=-1` because I use SumatraPdf).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I have tried both of your solutions. Unfortunately none of it worked. I can use all other Latex feature so I do not think it is a problem with pdflatex. Maybe it is a problem with Miktex 2.9 and Windows 8? But I think it is unlikely, since I have tried using both, the 32 and 64-bit Miktex version (my computer is running a 64-bit Windows 8).